# HTML5 + CSS and setting the width of <HEADER>

Tags: css, html

I got the following css:

```
div#header, header { 
    height: 88px; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-image: url('/images/header.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div id="header"></div>
```

The second HTML-line does exactly what I want it to do. However, the first html-line (< header >) does not.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.8. In firebug the markup for both html-line looks exactly the same. 
In Internet explorer I have the same problem. Only Chrome displays the code as expected.

I'm pretty confused right now. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 does not have a User Agent stylesheet that recognizes the `header` elements as block level elements, so as with all unknown elements it is displayed as an inline element.

Adding in this line should do the trick:

```
display: block;
```

Make sure that you use a HTML5 reset so that these elements display correctly for older browsers that do not recognize these new elements as block level elements, like:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display:block; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem in Firefox. Is there a way to fix it for IE?

Comment: @Stegeman For IE8 and below, you need to create the elements inside the DOM before they can be styled. See: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use HTML5 elements like `header` and It needs to work in older browsers like ie 6, 7 & 8. Than in addition to adding `display: block`; to the elements, you may have to use a javascript workaround that targets ie.

Here is an example from communitymx.com that does this for a several HTML5 elements:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var html5elmeents = "address|article|aside|audio|
        canvas|command|datalist|details|dialog|
        figure|figcaption|footer|header|hgroup|
        keygen|mark|meter|menu|nav|progress|
        ruby|section|time|video".split('|');

      for(var i = 0; i < html5elmeents.length; i++){
            document.createElement(html5elmeents[i]);
        }
    }
  )();
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Source: [Making HTML5 work in IE6, IE7 & IE8](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=8C170)

You may want to replace `<!--[if IE]>` with `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` if ie9 supports the elements the way you need it to.

Comment: Oh, just saw Yi Jiang's comment. The html5.js script looks pretty neat